# Highest Value Wrong Colour

Tags: json, bar-chart, visualization, vega-lite

Just made a simple bar chart, but for some reason, the final value is the wrong colour?
[image: Bar Chart]

Code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 600,
    "title": "Death Rates Amongst Ages",
    "data": {"url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/githubuser0099/Repo55/main/AgeBracket_DeathRate.csv"},
    "transform": [
        {"calculate":"parseInt(datum.Death_Rate)", "as": "Death_Rate"}
      ],
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Death_Rate", "type": "quantitative", "title": ""},
        "y": {"field": "Age", "type": "nominal", "title": "", "sort": "-x"},
        "color": {
            "field": "Age", 
            "type": "nominal", 
            "scale": {"scheme": "reds"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think color gradients are showing as per the selected predefined color scheme. In this case "reds"

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your colour scale is: "Age" is currently encoded as a string (nominal variable). You define the type of "Age" as "nominal", but use a sequential colour scale ("reds"). Your data also has some issues - there are some empty spaces before 5-9, and 10-14.

[image: data problem]

In string comparison, white space < "0" < "100" < "15".

To solve the issue, we can get the first number from the range, and then define another channel to encode this first number (but hide the legend), then in the colour channel, you can define the colour order based on this additional channel.

Check the result and the codes below.

[image: Result]

I have printed out the data and let you know how the calculation works.

```
{
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
"width": 800,
"height": 600,
"title": "Death Rates Amongst Ages",
"data": {"url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/githubuser0099/Repo55/main/AgeBracket_DeathRate.csv"},
"transform": [
    {"calculate":"parseInt(datum.Death_Rate)", "as": "Death_Rate"},
    {"calculate": "split(datum['Age'], '-')[0]", "as": "Age_new"},
    {"calculate": "replace(datum['Age_new'], ' ', '')", "as": "Age_new_2"},
    {"calculate": "replace(datum['Age_new_2'], ' ', '')", "as": "Age_new_3"},
    {"calculate": "parseInt(datum['Age_new_3'])", "as": "Age_new_4"}
  ],
"mark": "bar",
"encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Death_Rate", "type": "quantitative", "title": ""},
    "y": {"field": "Age", "type": "nominal", "title": "", "sort": "-x"},
    "opacity":{"field": "Age_new_4", "legend": null},
    "color": {
        "field": "Age", 
        "type": "ordinal", 
        "sort": "opacity",
        "scale": {"scheme": "reds"}
    }
}
```

}[image: Data]

Cheers,
KL

Comment: Ohhh, I assumed that the "field" element within "color", had to be "Age", as I was colouring individual age brackets, and because that field was already sorted, the "reds" scheme would be applied to this sorted field.

I had no idea it was simply colouring the the different age bracket strings, based on what values they have in numeric form, thanks for the clarification there Kane!